# Minikube mount fails with input/output error

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Kinda what it says on the tin. I try doing `minikube mount /some/dir:/home/docker/other_dir &`, and it fails with the following error:

```
Mounting /some/dir into /home/docker/other_dir on the minikube VM
This daemon process needs to stay alive for the mount to still be accessible...
ufs starting
ssh command error:
command : 
sudo mkdir -p /home/docker/other_dir || true;
sudo mount -t 9p -o trans=tcp,port=38902,dfltuid=1001,dfltgid=1001,version=9p2000.u,msize=262144 192.168.99.1 /home/docker/other_dir;
sudo chmod 775 /home/docker/other_dir;
err     : exit status 1
output  : chmod: changing permissions of '/home/docker/other_dir': Input/output error
```

Then, when I do a `minikube ssh` and `ls -l` inside `/home/docker`, I get this:

```
$ ls -l
ls: cannot access 'other_dir': Input/output error
total 0
d????????? ? ?   ?   ?            ? other_dir
```

**UPDATE:**

After some experimenting, it looks like the problem arises when `/some/dir` has a user other than the current user. Why this is the case is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

which version of minikube are you running ? It' working for me on minikube version `v0.20.0`.

`minikube mount /tmp/moun/:/home/docker/pk
Mounting /tmp/moun/ into /home/docker/pk on the minikube VM
This daemon process needs to stay alive for the mount to still be accessible...
ufs starting`

It's working good and I can create file too,

`$ touch /tmp/moun/cool`

we can check file at,

`$ minikube ssh
$ ls /home/docker/pk
cool`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1822
You'll need to run the minikube mount command as that user if you want to mount a folder owned by that user.